# How can I use a value from inside a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm creating a method that's essentially trying to grab the mean of an array. I initialized an integer sum to 0 outside of the for loop, ran the for loop, and tried returning the sum.
This is what my code looks like:

```java
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
         {
              sum += array2[i];
              return sum;
         }
    return sum / array2.length;
```

Upon running, it only returns the value I originally initialized sum to.
(I didn't include the code for array2, just assume I initialized it beforehand.)

Comment: if return is inside for-loop, after first iteration will exit loop

Comment: "it only returns the value I originally initialized sum to" that seems only possible if `array2[0]` is 0.

Comment: All that head scratching and gritted teeth was all because of an incorrect return placement. My problem was fixed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
 {
      sum += array2[i]; // sum is increased, but only for i==0
      return sum;       // loop is left first time, making loop futile
 }
return sum / array2.length; // never reached for length > 0
```

The problem is the return inside the loop, which cannot ever be what you want.
Just delete the `return sum;` to have the second return do what you intend it to,

i.e. loop over the length of the array, accumulate `sum` and after the loop retrn the average.

By the way, if you observe that `sum` is returned as initialised, it can be if `array[0]` is 0, otherwise not.